# Update value of closest span by class name if value found in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` with two `spans` inside, I am checking to see if a text already exists inside inside that `div`, if it does then update the text inside of a `span`.

Here's the structure of my div:

```
<div class="top-cart-items">

<div class="top-cart-item clearfix">
<div class="top-cart-item-desc">Orange Club
<span class="top-cart-item-price">£2.99</span>
<span class="top-cart-item-quantity">x1</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="top-cart-item clearfix">
<div class="top-cart-item-desc">Blue Tang
<span class="top-cart-item-price">£2.99</span>
<span class="top-cart-item-quantity">x1</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="top-cart-item clearfix">
<div class="top-cart-item-desc">Soft Ball
<span class="top-cart-item-price">£3.99</span>
<span class="top-cart-item-quantity">x1</span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

When a string is found inside `.top-cart-item-desc` I want to update the `.top-cart-item-quantity` using jQuery. There are a lot of divs and spans with the same names so I am unable to find where the string was found and update that.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var price = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
    var quantity = 1;
        if($('.top-cart-item-desc').text().indexOf(name) != -1)
            {
            $(this).closest('.top-cart-item-desc span.top-cart-item-quantity').text('15');
            }
});
```

I have also tried `siblings()` and `find()` but none of those worked either.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tg6vo7L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing a map variable to store new items added, then you can:

```
items[item].find('span.top-cart-item-quantity')
```

link:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ajzmLnr/

Comment: Yes perfect, I actually did that but I was confused I needed to add `return false`.

Comment: @AbuNooh where did you have to add `return false`? If you'll paste your solution i wouldn't mind taking a look at it and trying to help.

Comment: Ok it turns out that it updates all the classes with `top-cart-item-quantity` I need only the closest one to be updated. Had to remove accepted answer but upvoted instead.

Comment: @AbuNooh yes, you are right, you need to refer to `this` like so: `$(this).children('span.top-cart-item-quantity')`

Comment: I've added a fiddle in the question. BTW tried `$(this).children('span.top-cart-item-quantity')` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @AbuNooh Ok, the fiddle made it much clearer, try introducing a dictionary to keep track of the items here is a link: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3ajzmLnr/)

Comment: Cheers for your perseverance, the dictionary was a great addition and solved my problem and I would've needed to add an array at some point anyway! Accepting as answer if you want to add the link it the answer then it might help others.